# how to access gameObject in a unity action closure

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, closures

In Unity I have this piece of code :

```
var go = gameObject;
var some=123;
Debug.Log(go);
socket.On("login", _ => {
    Debug.Log("1");
    Debug.Log(some);
    Debug.Log(go);
    Debug.Log("2");
});
```

Simply I want to access the variable go, but as that is outside the closure and type of GameObject, it can't be accessed.

In the console :

```
HomeObject
1
123
```

But everything after calling that HomeObject disappears.

**How can I access my own class/gameObject in the closure?**

Answer (score 0):

Keep that object above in the hierarchy.

If I am not mistaken your GameObject is being destroyed before than callback from the socket.

You can check that by loging:

```
....

socket.On("login", _ => {
            Debug.Log("Socket callback");
        });

void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Called before than send callback");
        //if destroyed you can't access `gameObject`
        //keep the object above in the calling hierarchy, or cancel request.
    }
```